# How do I list a special project on my resume?

Tags: resume, projects

I'm hoping to get a job in management.  Currently my only management experience is leading a special project at my current company.  This project was a part time thing.  I had about fifteen people working on this project, and everyone was expected to put in around 10% of their time for project related tasks.  My regular job at this company had very little to do with this project.

How should I list this on my resume?  I worked on the project for a year and a half, and it was a high profile thing for my company.  I never had a title change for this project, and my regular title would not indicate any management tasks.  I feel that I should prominently display this on my resume, but since it accounted for a small portion of my other job, how do I account for it without making it seem like it was a full time thing?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'd say it depends on the industry, for instance a lot of game devs have to wear many hats on the same project so it's easier to layout some portion of their resume *around* the titles they've shipped.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to note that Project Management (which it sounds like what you did) and "People" Management are two very different skills and have their own unique career paths. In my experience it is rare to be immediately promoted into people management from outside a company if you aren't already a people manager. The best way to "rise through the ranks" so to speak, is to take an associate position and impress someone in management so that they mentor you and eventually assist you in taking the step from associate to manager.

That said, any special experience in line with your end-goals is worth noting on your resume. I like to call this type of work "Selected Accomplishments" on my resume and I list them under each individual position I have filled. In addition, if I feel that one of these selected accomplishments constitutes a skill (such as *Project Management*) then I also highlight that skill at the top of my resume.

I have had good success with this layout and have listed an example below for reference with the section highlighted where I think your project experience should go.

*Note: I work in IT so the System Experience section might not be as important to your industry.*

[image]